# Capture Video & Audio for streaming & recording. Can it be done?

Tags: audio, video, streaming

I have looked for a solution for a few of days and will continue to do so, but I wanted to go over what I’m trying to achieve to first make sure it CAN be done before going forward.

My goal is to use my RPi3 and the Official v2 Camera along with a sourced microphone as voice input to be able to broadcast live video WITH AUDIO.

Currently I’ve found that due to not having an audio input source many just resort to a 3rd party USB webcam which provides Video & Audio. My intent is to first see if you can obtain audio input via  https://www.adafruit.com/products/1713 or a USB mic while still using the On board Camera. Recording video and using the mic to capture the audio and having them sync for the video stream.

All suggestions and advice is appreciated.